# Logarithm to base 3 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, logarithm

I am trying to find the logarithm of a number to base 3 using python.

Here is the problem :

https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-three/description/

I am using this code:

```
import math
math.log(k,3)
```

However, it is failing for some test cases like (there are some more test cases):

```
math.log(243,3)

#output
4.999999999999999

math.log(59049,3)

#output
9.999999999999998
```

I do not want to use `round()` as it will round other numbers which are not the powers of 3.

Here is the full code which I am using:

```
class Solution:
    def isPowerOfThree(self, n: int) -> bool:
        import math
        k = abs(n)
        if n<=0:
            return False
        return math.log(k,3) == int(math.log(k,3))
```

Note: I am looking for solutions involving logarithms. Please feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: The code should check if you can divide n by 3 (without remainder) repeatedly until the result is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just typical [floating-point error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).  Recall that when you write `math.log(x, 3)`, Python is actually calculating something like `math.log(x) / math.log(3)`, with both (natural) log calculations and the division having to be rounded to the nearest `float`.

But if you do your math with `int` instead of `float`, exactness is preserved.

```py
def is_power_of_three(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return False
    while n > 1:
        n, r = divmod(n, 3)
        if r != 0:
            return False
    return n == 1
```

This checks if you can divide `n` by 3 (without remainder) until the result is 1.

Comment: Thanks @dan04... I understand. it is the floating point error for logarithms..

Answer (score 2):

If you still want an answer that uses logarithms. You can use the following code.

```py
def isPowerOfThree(self, n: int) -> bool:
    return n > 0 and n == 3**round(math.log(n, 3))
```

[LeetCode Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-three/solutions/2471010/python-log/)